# Remote gdb session receives signal SIGSEGV before entering main

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, cross-compiling, gdbserver

I'm trying to set up remote debugging using gdb 7.7 for an embedded linux platform, running code compiled with "i586-geode-linux-gnu-gcc (crosstool-NG 1.19.0) 4.8.1".

The example used here is the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(char* argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, 1!");
    printf("Hello, 2!");
    printf("Hello, 3!");

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using:

`i586-geode-linux-gnu-gcc -g test.c -o testsc`

Step 1. On target (over ssh):

```
# gdbserver :2345 testsc
Process testsc created; pid = 23623
Listening on port 2345
```

Step 2. On the host PC:

```
chetic@ubuntu:~/Documents/tmp/remotetest$ gdb testsc 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from testsc...done.
```

Step 3. I suspect this isn't right:

```
(gdb) target remote 192.168.1.102:2345
Remote debugging using 192.168.1.102:2345
Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
0x40000c80 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

Step 4:

```
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x4000f9ef in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
(gdb)
```

I've tried setting a breakpoint at main, but it is not encountered. Everything works fine for debugging if I run the program with gdb on target, or compile using regular gcc and run a remote session locally on the pc host.

I have compiled and installed gdb 7.7 and gdbserver 7.7 for both target and host on the host machine.

Googling this problem mostly suggests changing the stack size but I have tried changing the stack size limit using 'ulimit -s' with different values (including unlimited) and seen in /proc/[pid]/maps that the stack is affected, but the problem remains.

Memory map (this example used 'ulimit -s unlimited'):

```
# cat /proc/`pidof gdbserver`/maps
08048000-08090000 r-xp 00000000 03:01 60919      /usr/bin/gdbserver
08090000-08092000 rw-p 00048000 03:01 60919      /usr/bin/gdbserver
08092000-080be000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
40000000-4001f000 r-xp 00000000 03:01 45729      /lib/ld-2.17.so
4001f000-40020000 r--p 0001f000 03:01 45729      /lib/ld-2.17.so
40020000-40021000 rw-p 00020000 03:01 45729      /lib/ld-2.17.so
40021000-40022000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
40022000-40024000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
40025000-40028000 r-xp 00000000 03:01 45726      /lib/libdl-2.17.so
40028000-40029000 r--p 00002000 03:01 45726      /lib/libdl-2.17.so
40029000-4002a000 rw-p 00003000 03:01 45726      /lib/libdl-2.17.so
4002a000-40195000 r-xp 00000000 03:01 45711      /lib/libc-2.17.so
40195000-40196000 ---p 0016b000 03:01 45711      /lib/libc-2.17.so
40196000-40198000 r--p 0016b000 03:01 45711      /lib/libc-2.17.so
40198000-40199000 rw-p 0016d000 03:01 45711      /lib/libc-2.17.so
40199000-4069e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bfb24000-bfb39000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

Comment: Do you also have i586-geode-linux-gnu-gdb or similar? If you do, use this to connect to gdbserver.

Comment: No, which is why I compiled gdb myself. On the host PC, "show configuration" in gdb shows: "--host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=i586-geode-linux-gnu" which looks fine to me, unless there's anything else I should be worried about when compiling gdb for this kind of usage?

Comment: Sorry, that is fine (I thought you were using host gdb, which could or could not be compatible for your target).

Comment: Unless you "set sysroot", gdb will try to read things from the local file system.  This is rarely correct (see the /lib/ld-linux messages...).  I recommend that before "target remote" you do "set sysroot remote:".  This may help a bit.

Comment: Did you find a solution?